# How to download "com.dalsemi.onewire" package?

Tags: java

I want to run uniCent open source in my laptop but don't able to find onewire library. my import are:

```
import com.dalsemi.onewire.OneWireAccessProvider;
import com.dalsemi.onewire.adapter.DSPortAdapter;
import com.dalsemi.onewire.container.OneWireContainer;
import com.dalsemi.onewire.application.monitor.*;
```

How can I download these jar files?

Comment: this will help https://github.com/rusakovichma/owapi if you are using maven

Comment: through this link I try to add dependency but get "Could not find artifact com.dalsemi.onewire:owapi:pom:1.10 in unicenta-repo (http://repo.unicenta.org/maven2/)" error. what should I do now

Comment: did you add the repository info

Comment: Yes I add repository also but found "Unrecognised tag: 'repository' (position: START_TAG seen ...</dependency>\r\n\r\n    <repository>... @201:17)  @ C:\Users\User\Downloads\unicentaoposee\pom.xml, line 201, column 17
" error.

Comment: add the repository above the dependencies not in dependency

Answer (score 0):

**Locate the repositories section and replace it with this :**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>unicenta-repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.unicenta.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <url>https://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <id>restapi</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[restapi]</name>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>central-maven-repo</id>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

**Add below dependency :**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dalsemi.onewire</groupId>
    <artifactId>owapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Give it a try by running `mvn clean install` command.